# ipa-server failed to make a configuration?

Tags: centos, freeipa

I want to make a configuration for `ipa-server` on Centos 7. But I can't do it as I get this message:

```
DNS zone example.com already exists in DNS and is handled by servers: ns1.uniregistrymarket.link ns2.uniregistrymarket.link
```

What I did:

- Configure `192.168.10.10 server1.example.com` in `/etc/hosts`
- `ipa-server-install`

But I got this message.

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random `hostname` like `server1.ipa.local`. I had the same issue. This is recommended only for test environments. If you are going live better to purchase a domain. Hope this helps.